# How to reduce this Swift NSLayoutConstraint code?

Tags: swift, nslayoutconstraint

After created label, button etc. I use the function for the layout. Call the function in viewdidload and its working very vell. But I am not happy with the NSLayoutConstraint codes. How to reduce this code? Can use extension for this?

[iphne 5s and Xs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8VVH.jpg)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        buildUI()
    }
```

```
    private func buildUI() {
        view.backgroundColor = .lightGray

        view.addSubview(contentView)
        view.addSubview(usernameTextField)
        view.addSubview(passwordTextField)
        view.addSubview(forgotPasswordButton)
        view.addSubview(loginButton)
        view.addSubview(createAccountButton)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            contentView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 32),
            contentView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -32),
            contentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 354),
            contentView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),

            usernameTextField.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 32),
            usernameTextField.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor, constant: -32),
            usernameTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 24),
            usernameTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),

            passwordTextField.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 32),
            passwordTextField.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor, constant: -32),
            passwordTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: usernameTextField.topAnchor, constant: 64),
            passwordTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),

            forgotPasswordButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            forgotPasswordButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: passwordTextField.topAnchor, constant: 70),

            loginButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: createAccountButton.bottomAnchor, constant: -46),
            loginButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 32),
            loginButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor, constant: -32),
            loginButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),

            createAccountButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor),
            createAccountButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -30),

            ])
    }
```

Comment: You could create your own extension where you define new functions that you can call on a buttons, text fields, etc. like `exampleButton.centerInSuperview()` or `button.fillSuperview()` but I don't think you can shorten this much otherwise.

Comment: You could remove the redundant negative constans if you align the centerX anchor instead of pinning the right anchor. Although I'm not sure if that will impact the performance of the layout engine. Other than that your code is pretty organized given you are using the system methods.

Comment: Nit: The constraint where the bottom of the `loginButton` is pinned to the bottom of the `createAccountButton` with a negative constant looks weird. I think you meant to pin the top of `createAccountButton` to the bottom of `loginButton` with a positive constant.

Comment: Thanks four your comments. I can not remove the negative constants because different screen sizes to keep the same spaces from the edges.

Comment: If you had any more views I would suggest converting to a [`UIStackView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview). Then you could just specify the views you want to arrange in a stack and the `UIStackView` will create the constraints for you.

Comment: @kezi You're right about stackview but it is very difficult to create with code for me. I added image iphone 5s and XS, I hope its explain why I used negative constants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an extension I use. Documentation included. I don't use center anchors much but if you really need them you can easily add them to the extension.

```
extension UIView {
    /**
     Anchors a view using the input constraints.
     - Parameter top: The top constraint.
     - Parameter leading: The leading or left contraint.
     - Parameter bottom: The bottom constraint.
     - Parameter trailing: The trailing or right contraint.
     - Parameter padding: The padding to be applied to the constraints. Requires init with UIEdgeInsets.
     - Parameter size: The size to be added to the view. Requires init with CGSize. If all other constraints are set, sizes do not have any effect.
     */

    func anchor(top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, leading: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, trailing: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, padding: UIEdgeInsets = .zero, size: CGSize = .zero) {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        if let top = top { topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top, constant: padding.top).isActive = true }
        if let leading = leading { leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leading, constant: padding.left).isActive = true }
        if let bottom = bottom { bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom, constant: -padding.bottom).isActive = true }
        if let trailing = trailing { trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailing, constant: -padding.right).isActive = true }
        if size.width != 0 { widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.width).isActive = true }
        if size.height != 0 { heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.height).isActive = true }
    }
}
```

Here is an example of how to use it and how it clearly reduces the number of lines:

```
usernameTextField.anchor(top: contentView.topAnchor, leading: contentView.leadingAnchor, bottom: nil, trailing: contentView.trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 24, left: 32, bottom: 0, right: 32), size: .init(width: 0, height: 50))
```

Comment: Thank you for this extension. I think it's gonna work. I have a little error only top constraint.  if I can solve the problem I will write here. Error is ``` Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?' ``` But I am working on it

Comment: @John topConstraint expects a `NSLayoutYAxisAnchor` if you need to add padding to it use the `padding` parameter of the method. You can just do `.init(top: theValue, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)`

Comment: When using old code I write left and right anchor, width was coming automatically. After this function it doesn't work. And sometimes I use left or right anchor with centerX or centerY anchor. This function doesn't have this option. Other options works fine. Thanks again.

Comment: @John Yep, I normally prefer to use leading and training anchor for all the views. `centerAnchors` are, for me, a bit more difficult to keep track of. So I almost never use them. But you can easily add them, just follow the pattern of the method. Just remember that each view should have 4 constraints in any combination, 2 vertical and 2 horizontal. Otherwise you will get ambiguous constraints or warnings

Comment: Thank you for extension and explanation @Galo Torres Sevilla